# How does Bloodhound fit into typeahead.js?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I'm trying to understand how Twitters typeahead.js library works but I don't really understand what Bloodhound, the 'suggestion engine' does beyond acting as a source for the typeahead object.

Some of my concrete questions are:

- What is a query? What is a datum? What do they look like and where do I get them from
- Why do I need to tokenize my queries and datums?
- What happens with the tokenized queries and datums?

I'd read the source code, but my Javascript is not that advanced ... The documentation is really unclear to me, as it's mostly examples and seems to be targeted at people who have implemented a typeahead in a specific way already.

If someone would be so kind to explain conceptually how it works I'd be very grateful.

Best regards,
Joshua

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed step-by-step **[Typeahead Tutorial @Digital Fortress](http://digitalfortress.tech/tutorial/smart-search-using-twitter-typeahead-bloodhound/)** with **JS Fiddles** to get you started with how Bloodhound and Typeahead work together.

Here are a *few extracts* from the Tutorial on what I deduced:

- **What is a query?** A query is the text that the user types into the text box
- **What is a datum?** A datum is a single suggestion. (A string)
- **Why do I need to tokenize my queries and datums?** Tokenizing means to convert a string into an array of smaller strings (called *tokens*). It is done to ease searching operation. For example, take the string *"hello super man"*. You can convert this string into 3 smaller strings by splitting them by the whitespace character. So, `"hello super man"` would become `["hello","super","man"]` and would ease in searching for words beginning/containing `hello`, `super` and/or `man`.
- **What happens with the tokenized queries and datums?** These are used by the Bloodhound engine to return suggestions to the user. Bloodhound matches the queries and the datums and returns the results as suggestions to the user.

**Note**: The official Typeahead library has **NOT** received any updates since 3+ years now(ref [github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/commits/master)). But there's an actively maintained [fork](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js) (as of 2018) which should be used instead.

**[Reference](http://digitalfortress.tech/tutorial/smart-search-using-twitter-typeahead-bloodhound/)**